# How to simple overwrite showContextMenu on all columns of a grid?

Tags: axapta

If I overwrite showContextMenu on a grid it only add additional menu to the pop up menu when I click on a grid but do not click on any column. One way is to overwrite showContextMenu on all columns in grid but this solution does not looks right. Is there some better way how to insertItem to showContextMenu on all columns of a grid?

I am using AX 2012.

Standard code works only if grid is clicked but not a single column of a grid.

```
int ret,ii;
int                     myMenu = 2;
PopupMenu               popupMenu = PopupMenu::create(_menuHandle);
FormListItem item;
;
deleteAttachment = popupMenu.insertItem('My menu');

ret = super(_menuHandle);

if(ret == myMenu)
{
    //My code
}

return ret;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use method `registerOverrideMethod`.

You can test how it works as follows. E.g. you have a form with a grid (property `Name` = 'Grid', `AutoDeclaration` = 'Yes'), and there are a few StringEdit controls in that grid.

1) Create following method in your form:

```
public void formControlContext(FormStringControl _formStringControl)
{
    _formStringControl.context();
    info(strFmt(@"Overridden context of control '%1'", _formStringControl.name()));
}
```

2) Override method `init` in your form:

```
public void init()
{
    FormStringControl fsc;
    int controlNum;

    super();

    for (controlNum = 1; controlNum <= Grid.controlCount(); controlNum++)
    {
        fsc = Grid.controlNum(controlNum);
        fsc.registerOverrideMethod(methodStr(FormStringControl, context), identifierStr(formControlContext));
    }
}
```

You only need to modify method 'formControlContext' according to your needs.

**P.S.** I just noticed you need to override method `showContextMenu` anot not `context`. The idea is the same - use `registerOverrideMethod`. You can override any method this way.

Answer (score 2):

I've never played with overwriting the ShowContextMenu, but I did just make a blog post about how to recursively loop over every form control that sounds like it might help you.

http://alexondax.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-use-recursion-to-loop-over-form.html

I'd imagine you could create some sort of handler and key/value thing if you're creative.